# Convert Numpy array to image

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

I have a little nasty problem. I have a numpy array filled with float values. The background is that the array's values represent the water depth of a square grid.

```
345.34 888.78 999.35
300.00  98.00  88.45
440.89 423.56  11.68
```

I want to convert/save this array as image. Thereby, a range of values shall be represented by one color.

```
"dark blue" "midnight blue" "midnight blue"       #00008B #191970 #191970
"dark blue" "medium blue"   "medium blue"    or   #00008B #0000CD #0000CD 
"navy"      "navy"          "blue"                #000080 #000080 #0000FF
```

I circumvented this problem by saving the array as ASCII file and converting it in ArcGIS to a raster map but I want to avoid ArcGIS since I have too many arrays/maps to do it manually.

My attempt was to replace a range of values with integers through masks. Then I convert the replaced float values to strings and replace the strings with the RGB color codes. I finally use Image.fromarray to create an image. The result is a mess. It does not resemble an inundation map.

I hope somebody knows a doable way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that simply passing your data to `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()`. The color scale can be [adjusted by the color map](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) of your choice. Assuming you have the data saved in a text file:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('data.txt')
plt.imshow(data, cmap=cm.Blues)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I know there is something like that. great!